# Magento 2: Add Grid Column to Admin Sales Order Without Adding Column to Database?

Tags: php, magento2

I want to add a column to sales order grid on magento admin dashboard. But the value of the column is from some process, not from database. Is that possible? And how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column to the admin grid by adding a file called `view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` to your custom module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="order_reference" class="Vendor\Example\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Example">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Example Column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Your `Example.php`-file should extend `Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column` and have a `prepareDataSource()`-method to populate the data:

```
/**
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $item[$this->getData('name')] = 'Something'
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

Note that if you want to add sort- and filter-options you need to add some other adjustments, but that depends on what kind of data you want to show in the column.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but do you happen to know a good source / tutorial for adding sort- and filter-options?

Comment: using this i can get this text "something" in grid for everty order but i want to get dynamic value instead of that.... so what should i do for that ?

Comment: @Giel Berkers  do you think you could expand on your answer with an example of adding sorting for the dynamic column? It seems that when sorting it will throw an error because the column does not exist in the DB.